# Why am I not able to see the source code of my maven plugin in intellij?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-plugin

I am developing a new maven plugin. I have included the plugin under development to another project's pom.xml for testing purposes. I am using intellij idea as my IDE. Problem is that I am not able to navigate to my plugins source files from my test project. The project is compiling and I am able to access source code of my other dependent libraries but none from any of the maven plugins. How to solve this ? Below is how I have configured my plugin in my test project.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>my.package</groupId>
                <artifactId>my-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.123-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>my.package</groupId>
                        <artifactId>my-custom-plugin-add-on</artifactId>
                        <version>0.0.123-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>my-check</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>mygoal</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

</build>
```

Comment: Show us the pom for the test project?

Comment: @EngineerDollery I have added the pom for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve it by having a common super pom.xml for both the project I want to test and the plugin project.

```
Parent Project
   - The Project using maven plugin. (with the plugin added to the package phase)
   - The maven plugin itself.
```

And then I will right click on the 'package' maven lifecycle phase for the project using maven plugin and select debug.